# Fetch object from JSON

Tags: ios, json

I am trying to fetch object from following from JSON file but getting error.I want to display this data to tbaleview.

> ```
> OrganizationList =     (
>             (
>         17,
>         TGB,
>         Ahmedabad,
>         "SG Highway",
>         Dover,
>         "Georgia",
>         388306,
>         12345,
>         "www.abc.com",
>         "37.23909",
>         "-122.34567",
>         "Dec 6, 2013 5:11:15 PM"
>     )
> );
> isError = 0;
> message = "Organization List is...";
> ```

I want to fetch "TGB" from this....
I have tried this

```
 for(int i=0;i<[tempDataArray count];i++){
    [temp addObject:[tempDataArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"temp%@",temp);
    [searchArray addObject:[temp objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"searcharray with name%@",searchArray);
    NSLog(@"name%@",[searchArray objectAtIndex:1]);
      }
```

Here is tempArray...

```
(
    (
    17,
    TGB,
    Ahmedabad,
    "SG Highway",
    Dover,
    "Georgia",
    388306,
    12345,
    "www.abc.com",
    "37.23909",
    "-122.34567",
    "Dec 6, 2013 5:11:15 PM"
)
 )

but this is giving me error index out of bound at index 1.
```

Comment: What is the nslog of `searchArray`?

Comment: show your code for json parsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tempArray is not just an array, means not a single dimension array, it's two-dimensional array.

```
    for(int i=0;i<[tempDataArray count];i++){
            NSArray *secondArray = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
            [temp addObject:secondArray];
            NSLog(@"temp%@",temp);
            for(int j=0; j < [secondArray count]; j++) {
                    [searchArray addObject:[secondArray objectAtIndex:j]];
            }
            NSLog(@"searcharray with name%@",searchArray);
            NSLog(@"name%@",[searchArray objectAtIndex:1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in tempDataArray)
{
    [yourTempArry addObject: dictionary];
}

for (NSString * sTemp in yourTempArry)
{
    NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp.LocationName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
        [searchArray addObject:sTemp];
}
```